# Add Criteria "not contain" in data table filter

Tags: vb.net, datatables

I want to replace this (SOPNUMBE<> 'VAT') with another that filter rows not contain "VAT" In the SOPNUMBE column

```
Dim newview As New DataView(NAJRNDataSet27.vwSalesInvoicePosted)
        Dim Cust_no As String = TextBox1.Text
        newview.RowFilter = $"CUSTNMBR = '{Cust_no}'  And  SOPNUMBE<> 'VAT'"
```

Comment: Have a look at the "Like" operator for row filters.  Can be inverted with a "Not"

Comment: Is CUSTNMBR a number in the database? If so, remove the single quotes from `'{Cust_no}'` . It should look like `CUSTNMBR = {Cust_no}`